# GetSaveFileName can't open user's temp-dir

Tags: c++

I use a similar function to get the path and the filename, which I want to use to save a file on a Windows 8.1 machine:

```
void TestFunc()
{
    OPENFILENAME ofn;
    WCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH] =        L"C:\\Users\\biber\\AppData\\Local\\temp\\test.txt";

    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn); 
    ofn.hwndOwner = NULL;
    ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)szFileName;
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
    ofn.Flags = OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = (LPCWSTR)L"txt";

    GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
    return ;
}
```

The problem is, that the SaveFileDialog doesn't show me initial the Temp-Path. If I change the szFileName to another path than the %TEMP%, it works.
It doesn't work with the temp path.

Comment: "I use this function to save a file" - but this function doesn't save a file...

Comment: Make sure you are running the application in Admin mode.

Comment: @HappyCoder: The temp-Path is my temp-path, so I think I don't need more Permissions to access it. Also if I type "%temp%" in the top path-field of the dialog it changed correctly to the temp-path.

Comment: But the temp path resides in C:\ drive. It is the same drive in which OS is installed. I think you need permissions to access it. Not sure though!

Comment: If I use the path:"C:\Users\biber\AppData\Local\test\test.txt" it works!

Comment: If I start the test-exe as admin it don't work also.

Comment: @Biber, do you get better results if you pass the temp path in `ofn.lpstrInitialDir`?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: That's it, if I set ofn.lpstrFile to Filename only and ofn.lpstrInitialDir to the directory only than it works, please post it as answer, then I will accept it as best answer.

Comment: @Biber, I could, but I won't, because I cannot explain the root cause behind the behavior you're experiencing. According to the documentation for [OPENFILENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx), *if `lpstrFile` contains a path, that path is the initial directory* [regardless of whether or not `lpstrInitialDir` is set]. Therefore, it should work without the workaround I suggested. Maybe someone will come up with an appropriate explanation in the future.